# Mixing mapped and calculated columns in SQLAlchemy 2.0 ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create an SQLAlchemy 2.0 ORM mapping that allows me to mix Mapped columns that exist in my database with "calculated" columns from a query.

Assume I have two tables product_catalog and amount_catalog. The product_catalog lists a series of products I am selling. The amount_catalog lists the volumes options for each product. The two tables are connected by a foreign key column called product_catalog_id.

```
product_catalog

| id | name          |
| -- | ------------- |             
| 1  | Apple Juice   |
| 2  | Cherry Juice  |


amount_catalog
    
| id | amount | unit        | product_catalog_id | 
| -- | ------ | ----------- | ------------------ | 
| 1  | 500    | milliliters | 1                  | 
| 2  | 1000   | milliliters | 1                  | 
| 3  | 500    | milliliters | 2                  |
```

What I am trying to do is create a class for product_catalog that also contains a calculated *amount_count* column in my python backend.

```
class ProductCatalog(IdBase):
"""Defines the details of the product catalog table in our SQL database."""
    __tablename__ = "product_catalog"
    id: Mapped[Integer] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[String]
    amount_count:[Integer] # please note this is not mapped
```

My plan is to dynamically generate the *amount_count* column in a query like the following

```
def get_products(self) --> list[ProductCatalog]: 
    amount_counts:Subquery = 
        select(
            AmountCatalog.product_catalog_id,
            func.count(AmountCatalog.id).label("amount_count"),
        )
        .select_from(AmountCatalog)
        .group_by(AmountCatalog.product_catalog_id)
        .subquery()

    result = session.execute(
        select(
            ProductCatalog.id, 
            ProductCatalog.name, 
            amount_counts.c.amount_count
        )
        .select_from(ProductCatalog)
        .outerjoin(
            amount_counts, 
            ProductCatalog.id == amount_counts.c.product_catalog_id)
        )

    return [ProductCatalog(**row._mapping) for row in rows] # type: ignore
```

Unfortunately pytest is now throwing the following error at me:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Type annotation for "ProductCatalog.amount_count" can't be correctly interpreted for Annotated Declarative Table form.  ORM annotations should normally make use of the `Mapped[]` generic type, or other ORM-compatible generic type, as a container for the actual type, which indicates the intent that the attribute is mapped. Class variables that are not intended to be mapped by the ORM should use ClassVar[].  To allow Annotated Declarative to disregard legacy annotations which don't use Mapped[] to pass, set "**allow_unmapped** = True" on the class or a superclass this class. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/zlpr)
> Check Python Test Logs for more details.

**Any thoughts on how to best solve the above situation?**

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I solved this as follows using a **column_property**. It took a bit to find, but the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) on this is actually quite thorough. At a high level:

> The column_property() function can be used to map a SQL expression in a manner similar to a regularly mapped Column.

My code ended up looking something like this:

```
class ProductCatalog(IdBase):
"""Defines the details of the product catalog table in our SQL database."""
    __tablename__ = "product_catalog"
    id: Mapped[Integer] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[String]
    amount_count: MappedSQLExpression[int] = column_property(
        select(func.count(AmountCatalog.id))
        .where(AmountCatalog.product_catalog_id == id)
        .correlate_except(AmountCatalog)
        .scalar_subquery()
    )
```